# How to draw an object to canvas coming from another class?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-canvas, surfaceview

I am trying to create a program wherein when I touch the screen of the device, a ball will come out and will animate. I put the image in a separate class because later on i will be needing multiple instances of this MyImage class so whenever i touch the screen another ball will come out.

I have MyImage class wherein it contains an image. this class is extended to View class. The override method onDraw is where the image is being animated (bouncing on the screen).

```
public class MyImage extends View {
Bitmap g;
float posY = 0;
float posX = 0;

boolean ud = true, lr = true;

public MyImage(Context context) {
    super(context);
    g = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ba);
}
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    canvas.drawBitmap(g, posX, posY, null);

    ...... //code for animating


    invalidate();
}
}
```

I want to create an object of this class so that this will animate to my other canvas from class MainActivity.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{
..... //declarations

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mySurfaceView = new MySurfaceView(this);
    mySurfaceView.setOnTouchListener(this);
    setContentView(mySurfaceView);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    ....
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    ....
}

 Thread myThread;   
 Canvas canvas;

 public class MySurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable{
    SurfaceHolder myHolder;
    boolean isRunnable = false;

    public MySurfaceView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        myHolder = getHolder();
    }
    public void pause(){
        ....
    }

    public void resume(){
        isRunnable = true;
        myThread = new Thread(this);
        myThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(isRunnable){
            if(!myHolder.getSurface().isValid()){
                continue;
            }
            canvas = myHolder.lockCanvas();
            canvas.drawRGB(100, 0, 0);

            myHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me) {
    .....

    switch(me.getAction()){
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        mi = new MyImage(this);

        canvas.drawBitmap(..) ;//Is it possible to convert object to Bitmap?

        break;
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

The problem is that I dont know how wil I make the object of MyImage to Bitmap so that I could draw it into the canvas. And also I am not really sure if what i did is right because in my MyImage class i already have a canvas which i think will cover the canvas from the main activity.
Could anyone help with this?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, I would probably change that approach. Creating a View for each ball makes not much sense. I would create one custom View. This View can then contain a List of balls. In the `onDraw()` method of that View you can draw all the balls. The balls can be just `Point` or `PointF` objects with a default radius in the beginning.

Something along the line of

```
private class MyView extends View {
    List<Point> balls;

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        for(Point p : balls){
            canvas.drawCircle(p.x, p.y, 10, myPaint);
        }
    }
}
```